# Обновление события в Zabbix 3.2

Tags: zabbix

Имеется Zabbix 3.2. В экране Мониторинг->Панель есть окно "Последние 20 событий". В этом окне отображаются результаты работы триггеров. Например событие Oracle:
"no space on tablespace -SYSTEM use 85%".

После срабатывания триггера значение 85% в реальности может изменится на худшее значение - 90%. Но показываться все равно будет 85%. Как заставить zabbix обновлять значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону макросов. Можно в названии триггера вставить макрос {ITEM.LASTVALUE}, который будет показывать последнее значение элемента данных указанный в триггере. 
Больше макросов на официальной документации https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/ru/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location

Comment: Спасибо - именно то что нужно